# How can I get default Time in yii2 Timepicker Widget?

Tags: php, yii2

It shows current time as default time with validation working,
but, I want custom default time.

Here is my code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'e_start_time')->widget(TimePicker::className(),  
     [
        'readonly' => true,                     
        'pluginOptions' => [
                'minuteStep' => 5,
                'showMeridian' => true,
        ],
        'options'=>[
            'class'=>'form-control',
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: which type of `TimePicker` used?

Comment: `kartik TimePicker` used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.
In that you can use `date('H:i', strtotime('-2 hour')` or `date('H:i', strtotime('+2 hour'))` or `'00:00'` as `'defaultTime'`.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'e_start_time')->widget(TimePicker::className(),  
     [
        'readonly' => true,                     
        'pluginOptions' => [
                'minuteStep' => 5,
                'showMeridian' => false,
                'defaultTime' => date('H:i', strtotime('-2 hour')),
        ],
        'options'=>[
            'class'=>'form-control',
        ],
    ]); ?>
```